# Overlaying an image with another non-rectangular image containing black pixels using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, overlay

I want to programmatically overlay an image, e.g. the blissfully familiar Windows XP wallpaper:

[image: Windows XP wallpaper]

with another non-rectangular image that contains black pixels, e.g. a standard large cursor icon:

[image]

Copy-pastoring the codes from [this](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html) and [this](https://theailearner.com/2019/03/26/image-overlays-using-bitwise-operations-opencv-python/) tutorial which both use OpenCV bitwise masking magic I arrived at:

```
import cv2 as cv

# Load two images
img1 = cv.imread('bliss.png') # The image I want the overlay to be diplayed on.
img2 = cv.imread('cursor.png') # The image I want to overlay with, containing black pixels.

# I want to put logo on top-left corner, So I create a ROI.
rows, cols, channels = img2.shape
roi = img1[0:rows, 0:cols ]

# Now create a mask of logo and create its inverse mask also.
img2gray = cv.cvtColor(img2, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv.threshold(img2gray, 20, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv.bitwise_not(mask)

# Now black-out the area of logo in ROI.
img1_bg = cv.bitwise_and(roi, roi, mask = mask_inv)

# Take only region of logo from logo image.
img2_fg = cv.bitwise_and(img2, img2, mask = mask)

# Put logo in ROI and modify the main image
dst = cv.add(img1_bg, img2_fg)
img1[0:rows, 0:cols ] = dst
cv.imshow('res',img1)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

During naive permutations of trying to find the right parameters for `cv.threshold` (including [thres and maxval arguments](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) as well as [thresholding types](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)), I always find that significant number of black pixels present in the original image are missing from the overlaid one. In the zoomed-in picture below on the left you can see the overlaid cursor and on the right is original copied one:

[image]

I reckon this loss of pixels is due to the grayscale conversion and/or the inverse (?) masking but could not figure out how or what to change in the code above. In the tutorials I linked above images not containing black pixels were used for the overlay and the results look fine. Is there a way to do the same with images containing black pixels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is, that you lose the black pixels in `cursor.png` at `cv.threshold(img2gray, 20, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)`. The remainder are the white pixels only, thus your mask is just too small. Since `cursor.png` has transparency information stored in it, you can use its alpha channel for your mask.

Here's your code, modified accordingly (I removed all of your comments; comments show my changes):

```py
import cv2 as cv

img1 = cv.imread('bliss.png')
img2 = cv.imread('cursor.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)         # Added cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED parameter to maintain alpha channel information

alpha = img2[:, :, 3]                                       # Save alpha channel for later use
_, alpha = cv.threshold(alpha, 5, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)    # Threshold alpha channel to prevent gradual transparency
img2 = cv.cvtColor(img2, cv.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)                 # Remove alpha channel information, so that code below still works

rows, cols, channels = img2.shape
roi = img1[0:rows, 0:cols ]

                                                            # img2gray no longer needed
mask = alpha                                                # Mask is just the alpha channel saved above
mask_inv = cv.bitwise_not(mask)

img1_bg = cv.bitwise_and(roi, roi, mask = mask_inv)

img2_fg = cv.bitwise_and(img2, img2, mask = mask)

dst = cv.add(img1_bg, img2_fg)
img1[0:rows, 0:cols ] = dst
cv.imshow('res',img1)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hopefully, the output image then looks like something you expected:

[image: Output]

Comment: This works a charm when I use the originally linked large cursor. However, with smaller cursor images (e.g. https://i.imgur.com/0YC5qVV.png), the loss of black pixels creep back: https://i.imgur.com/TWnalik.png.

Comment: @bugfoot I edited my answer. The original alpha channel contains some kind of "gradual" transparency, indicated by values `0 < x < 255`. I added `_, alpha = cv.threshold(alpha, 5, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)` to binarize the alpha channel. It now also works with the small cursor image you provided.